# Show code state at particular commit in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I can view code of last commit in Bitbucket. But how to bourse in code that was in particular commit? I can navigate to Commits and select required commit, but after clicking on selected commit I get only diff changes and I would like to have whole code state that was at this commit.

Is it possible to get possibility to browse code for particular commit like I can do for last commit?

Answer (score 2):

There is a button "View source" at the top right part of the screen. Example: this is a random repository I found among [all public repos](https://bitbucket.org/repo/all/): https://bitbucket.org/m-parente/asm-poincare-pub/

Go to commits, choose one: https://bitbucket.org/m-parente/asm-poincare-pub/commits/4999d0141c3703df894c61557029e2ba251e39f2

Click on "View source", see the tree at https://bitbucket.org/m-parente/asm-poincare-pub/src/4999d0141c3703df894c61557029e2ba251e39f2/